# How do the regular expression capture infinite groups?

Tags: python, regex

I need to match the following:

```
text[ - (option1 option2 .. optionN)]
```

- **text** may or may not have spaces
- **-** is literal and will only appear if there are any option
- can have infinite **options**

Examples:

```
rabbit
rabbit white
rabbit - onlyGif
rabbie - onlyGif recent
```

Currently, I got the following, which works:

```
^([\w ]+)(?:$|\s-\s(\w+)(?:\s(\w+))?(?:\s(\w+))?)
```

However, capture at least 3 options, and I need to capture N options. How to do this?

I'm using Python.

Comment: Does it need to be re? Your examples seem as it could be easily done by spltting by '-' and then by processing the right hand side of '-', by spleeting is as well on spaces. no regular expression needed.

Comment: I would like to do everything at once, if possible. But, yes, I thought to do that way.

Comment: I think doing it in two or three steps would be easier, and definitely more readable and maintainable. Your regex  is  already complicated and hard to follow.

Comment: @KeplerBR what's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj An array. The first element is **text** and the following the **options**; each option is an element of the array.

Comment: `re.findall(r'^\s*\w+(?:\s+\w+)*|\w+', s)`, riffind on @hwnd's answer and mine (now both deleted), may get you a step further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to have an unbounded number of capturing groups in Python regexes.  However, you can use one regex to match the entire expression and then use a second regex to parse the options.  For example:

```
match = re.match(r'^([\w ]+)(?:\s-((?:\s\w+)+))?$', input)
if match:
    text = match.group(1)
    if match.group(2):
        options = [m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(r'\w+', match.group(2))]
    else:
        options = []
```