# Placeholder within a text document

Tags: regex, delphi

I'm looking for a regular expression that will match $P{xxx} placeholders in a text document, where xxx is an expression having similar to JS like syntax to read json data. Examples:

```
$P{DATA}
$P{DATA.Customers}
$P{DATA.Customers[2].Name}
```

The expression should do the full match of placeholder and be able to group the items delimited by dots inside the brackets.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** adding Delphi tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will match inside the group `^\$P\{(.*)\}$`

for how to group by dots check out this answer here: [How do the regular expression capture infinite groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698616/how-do-the-regular-expression-capture-infinite-groups)

Comment: Although Matt's solution does exactly what I was asking for, Delphi's TRegEx class does not support capture collections. Hence, I opted for your advice to split the process. First, match the content inside the brackets, then match with [^.]+ the strings delimited by dots.

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex:

```
^\$P\{(?:([^}\.]+)(?:\.([^}\.]+))*)\}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vYRUY3/2)

Comment: Unfortunately it groups only first and last item, the last of those three examples fails.

Comment: which programming language is being used?

Comment: Delphi 10.2. I'm trying now to split the task as suggested by @ZzCalvinzZ, but of course would prefer it done with a single expression.

Comment: See the code in C# [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t5KOGw). you can see in the output that all groups are captured as expected. There should be a Delphi equivalent of doing it.

Comment: Indeed, your demo works just fine, but looked again into TRegEx class of Delphi, and Capture collections are not implemented as you demonstrated in C#. Never thought such issue would be platform dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Without the need of regex and if you can use the alcinoe library (https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe) then you can do it simply like this :

```
MyStr := ALFastTagReplace(MyStr, // SourceString
                          '$P{', // TagStart
                          '}', // TagEnd
                          function(const TagString: AnsiString;TagParams: TALStrings; ExtData: pointer; Var Handled: Boolean): AnsiString;
                          begin
                            if TagString = 'DATA.Customers' then ...
                            else if TagString = 'DATA.Customers[2].Name' then ...
                            else ...
                          end); // ReplaceProc
```

this function will be fired on each `$P{xxx}` tag and let you even the opportunity to replace then inside the original string. about the perf i guess it's will be much more fast then regex

Comment: Interesting library, will do some research. Thanks for the pointers.